# HTML position UL to share the same line with other spans

Tags: html, css

If you look at this jsFiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/jrXwf/1/

You will see the UL tag displaying a star rating, with text below it on the next line.

Is there any way to get everything on one line?

Thanks

Comment: For better markup never put block element inside inline element. SPAN is an inline element & UL is an block element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/jrXwf/5/

Add `display: inline-block` to your unordered list (or any other element that you want to behave that way). You could also float the element, but inline-block probably best represents what you want to accomplish with a minimum amount of hassle. You want to display the element inline, and you want it to have a display box which behaves like a block element (thus `inline-block` versus `inline`).

Your overall markup structure could/should be modified. As others have pointed out, nesting a `SPAN` inside `UL` is not legal. You also have a fairly complex structure that could possibly be simplified to use fewer elements.

Answer (score 1):

just use float left in your this class  `.any-rating { float:left; }`

or

here is the fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/jrXwf/15/

Answer (score 0):

first, remove the `<span>` surrounding that `<ul>` because it's illegal. you can't place a block-level element in an inline-level element.

then, style the `<ul>` with either

- `display:inline-block`
- `float:left`

Answer (score 0):

Add Style display : inline-block to ul with class any-rating

```
ul.any-rating.rating {
  display:inline-block;
}​
```

here is the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jrXwf/12/

Comment: `display : inline-block` is not properly supported in ie6